# Cannot install google-colab package

Tags: python, pandas, pip, google-colaboratory

No matter what I have tried I cannot install the google-colab package in python.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -IC:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpandas\_libs/algos.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\pandas\_libs/algos.obj
      algos.c
      ...
      ...
      pandas\_libs/algos.c(167625): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
```

I tried reinstalling pandas, removing it, removing python and reinstalling but noting seems to work.

Why is this issue even occurs? Is there any known fix to this issue?

Comment: try `conda install -c conda-forge google-colab` if you have Anaconda installed

Comment: I did that and it worked, but now using the `import google-colab` on google colab tells me the package is not installed.

Comment: Did you install anaconda right now? or had it before?

Comment: Installed it fresh, btw I'm using google colab with local environment

Comment: Ok, seems like your problem is solved, I add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with compiling package on windows. You can install the compiled version using Anaconda

```
conda install -c conda-forge google-colab
```